# Two Regexes for RegexFileFilter

Tags: java, regex, file

I have a folder which contains some files and I want to get some files using `RegexFileFilter`. I have already used one `Regex`. Now I want to filter the folder by using two different Regex. How can I do that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
FilenameFilter filenamefilter = new RegexFileFilter("^" + PREFIX_RZ_FILES + ".*\\" + SUFFIX_RZ_FILES + "$");
```

Comment: Use `"^(" + PREFIX_RZ_FILES + ".*\\" + SUFFIX_RZ_FILES + "|" + SECOND_REGEX + ")$"`